# Как сделать движение условного врага к игроку в юнити (RigidBody2d)

Tags: c#, unity3d, .net, move

Я много где искал ответ и находил то что мне не совсем нужно. У меня есть игра видом **Сверху**, в ней расположен игрок и враг, враг должен преследовать игрока. Внимание, не через  `Transform` а через `RigidBody2D`, т.е как видно враг должен преследовать игрока и просто долбиться в него. Мне не нужно ничего лишнего. Я пытался написать ИИ для врага используя уже написанный заранее скрипт передвижения игрока но таки не разобрался с направлением.

Вот код движения игрока по которому я хотел сделать ИИ врагу.
Цель: Сделать движение врага к игроку без использования `Transform`.

```
public class PlayerMove : MonoBehaviour
{
   private Vector2 MoveObject;
   private Rigidbody2D PhysicalMove;
   private int PlayerSpeed = 10;
   void Start()
   {
       PhysicalMove = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
   }
   void Update()
   {
       Vector2 InputData = new Vector2(Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal"), Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical"));
       MoveObject = InputData.normalized * PlayerSpeed;
   }
   private void FixedUpdate()
   {
       PhysicalMove.MovePosition(PhysicalMove.position + MoveObject * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
   }
}
```

Comment: unity AI follow player 2d

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пример того как можно решить данную задачу:
Скрипт вешаем на противника, в поле `player` указываем игрока.

```
   public Transform player;
   private Rigidbody2D rb;
   private Vector2 movement;
   private int speed = 5;
       
   void Start()
   {
       rb = this.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
     

   }
   void Update()
   {
       Vector3 direction = player.position - transform.position;
       float angle = Mathf.Atan2(direction.y, direction.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
       direction.Normalize();
       movement = direction;
   }
   private void FixedUpdate()
   {
       MoveChar(movement);
   }
   private void MoveChar(Vector2 direction)
   {
       rb.MovePosition((Vector2)transform.position + (direction * speed * Time.deltaTime));
       
   }
}
```